# Does our brain use up more ATP after smoking cannabis?

Tags: biochemistry, brain, human-physiology, energy, energy-metabolism

kind of an amateur here.

If the firing of the neurons' signals uses up some ATP, and smoking cannabis makes them fire off more quickly, do our brains use up more ATP to sustain that rapid firing?

Comment: The Biology.SE community has agreed that **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. In particular, it's helpful to cite references for claims in your question.

Comment: considering that it can hasten heartbeat and breathing, https://medicalxpress.com/news/2017-08-brain-cannabis-oxygen.html

Comment: IV THC injection increases glucose metabolism in chronic cannabis users..see https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Linda_Chang2/publication/5944014_Functional_Imaging_Studies_in_Cannabis_Users/links/5431fc150cf27e39fa9f9880.pdf